# ¿Cómo mantener un tamaño fijo en una interfaz grafica?

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

Estoy empezando a utilizar interfaces gráficas con JFrame y me ha surgido la duda de establecer una ventana con tamaño fijo, es decir que esta no se pudiera maximizar ni estirar por ninguno de sus costados.

```
    frame = new JFrame("Registro");
    frame.setBounds(500, 300, 300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
```

Éste es el frame que ocupo, junto a unos bloques de texto y dos botones se vería tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría mantener esté tamaño constantemente (300x300).

Agradezco vuestra ayuda.

Comment: prueba con `frame.setResizable(false);` o agrega más detalles a tu pregunta si no te sirve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

1. evitamos que el elemento pueda ser redimencionable
2. le colocamos un `size` por defecto

   `frame.setResizable(false);`

   `frame.setSize(300,300);`